# ffmpeg: video + scaled watermark with multiply filter applied

Tags: ffmpeg

after a night of trying different options with applying my watermark on a video, I gave up :).
What I tried to do is:

- scale video to desired size (i.e. scale=640x480)
- add watermark on its top left corner (10:10)
- marge video with watermark with `blend=all_mode='multiply'`

I've tried many options and that one I think is almost correct:

```
fmpeg -i "${2}${3}" -i ${WMARK} -r 20 -y \
             -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=${6}x${7}, setsar=sar=1[a];[a][1:0] overlay=0:0[b];[a][b]blend=all_mode='multiply'"  \
            -an -c:v libx264 -crf "${8}" -preset "${9}" -tune "${10}" \
            -profile:v high -level 4.0 -movflags +faststart \
            "${4}${5}";
```

but anyway I am getting errors.

The nearest what I am looking for is:

```
ffmpeg -i "${2}${3}" -i ${WMARK} -r 20 -y \
             -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=${6}:${7}[vi];[1:v][vi]scale2ref=(1510/408)*ih/3/sar:ih/3[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10"  \
             -pix_fmt yuv420p \
            -an -c:v libx264 -crf "${8}" -preset "${9}" -tune "${10}" \
            -profile:v high -level 4.0 -movflags +faststart \
            "${4}${5}";
```

- Video is scaled to desired resolution ($[6}:${7})
- watermark is scaled as well
- ... but I dunno how add blend=all_mode='multiply' to it.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: You're already combining the streams with the overlay. What's the reason for the multiply?

Comment: Watermark looks better. Any ideas for multiply,  @Gyan ?